# Cant resolve './features/reducers' when trying to import rootreducer Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { App } from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './features/reducers'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

But i get the error in the title when i have it like this. here is the folder structure
[image]

BoxReducer.js file contains the following code.

```
    import { boxConstants } from '../constants/BoxConstants';

export function boxes(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case boxConstants.GET_BOXES_SUCCESS:
        return {
          items: action.boxes
        };
      case boxConstants.GET_BOXES_FAILURE:
        return { 
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

Might be here i do something wrong. i just have a hard time to understand were the rootreducer comes from. From what i read it comes from Redux itself and is not something i need to create

Comment: Where's folder structure?

Comment: @PrakashSharma sorry somehow it got erased when posting

Comment: Can you show your file at `./features/reducers` ?

Comment: @novafluff Shouldn't it be `import rootReducer from './features/reducers/BoxReducer'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the folder structure features/reducers has a file named **BoxReducer.js**. Please try: `import rootReducer from './features/reducers/BoxReducer.js'`.
or if you want to keep
`import rootReducer from './features/reducers'` then please rename the file **BoxReducer.js** to **index.js**

If this also doesn't work then look into the BoxReducer.js file. If rootReducer module is not exported by default then add curly brackets around rootReducer, like {rootReducer} while importing.

You can try these ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the BoxReducer.js also in the import.

```
import rootReducer from './features/reducers/BoxReducer.js';
```